# Find substring range of NSString with unicode characters

Tags: ios, objective-c, unicode, nsstring

If I have a string like this.

```
NSString *string = @"1357"
```

To get a substring like `@"35"` you have to account for the fact the smiley face character take two bytes.

```
NSString *substring = [string substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(5, 4)];
```

Is there a way to get the same substring by using the actual character index so `NSMakeRange(3, 3)` in this case?

Comment: you should try NSRangeFromString(@"35")

Comment: NSString supported unicode. Just try to test again with correct unicode text. It should be a readable text.

Comment: The problem with rangeOfString is if I need to find different occurrences of the same string.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Read UTF8 character in specify position from a NSString](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5100030/read-utf8-character-in-specify-position-from-a-nsstring)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Joe's link I was able to create a solution that works.

This still seems like a lot of work for just trying to create a substring at unicode character ranges for an NSString.  Please post if you have a simpler solution.

```
@implementation NSString (UTF)
- (NSString *)substringWithRangeOfComposedCharacterSequences:(NSRange)range
{
    NSUInteger codeUnit = 0;
    NSRange result;
    NSUInteger start = range.location;
    NSUInteger i = 0;
    while(i <= start)
    {
        result = [self rangeOfComposedCharacterSequenceAtIndex:codeUnit];
        codeUnit += result.length;
        i++;
    }

    NSRange substringRange;
    substringRange.location = result.location;
    NSUInteger end = range.location + range.length;
    while(i <= end)
    {
        result = [self rangeOfComposedCharacterSequenceAtIndex:codeUnit];
        codeUnit += result.length;
        i++;
    }   

    substringRange.length = result.location - substringRange.location;
    return [self substringWithRange:substringRange];
}
@end
```

**Example:**

```
NSString *string = @"1357";
NSString *result = [string substringWithRangeOfComposedCharacterSequences:NSMakeRange(3, 3)];   
NSLog(@"%@", result); // 35
```

Comment: Just to be clear, composed character sequences are not the same thing as code points. Your method is misleadingly named.

Comment: If you can edit and suggest a better name that would be great.

Comment: Well, you could call it `-substringWithRangeOfComposedCharacterSequences:` or something. The important thing is to understand the distinction.

Answer (score 0):

Make a swift extension of NSString and use new swift String struct. Has a beautifull String.Index that uses glyphs for counting characters and range selecting. Very usefull is cases like yours with emojis envolved

Comment: I'm using Objective-C.

Comment: No problem Berry you can merge two languages in a project. It's very easy